# Index all rows between two specific character values in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have created a data frame z.

```
a = c(1,1,1)
b = c("start",2,2)
c = c(3,3,3)
d = c("end",4,4)

z = data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
z
```

How can I index to get the row numbers between "start" and "end" if I don't know how many rows are going to be between "start" and "end"? In this instance there is only one row between "start" and "end" but for the next dataset there may be 50 rows between "start" and "end". Is there a way to use "start" and "end" to extract all the rows between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rows that are between start and end, but not include those actual rows, you could do

```r
seq(which(z$X1 == 'start') + 1, which(z$X1 == 'end') - 1)
#> [1] 3
```

Or, to get the row(s) itself

```r
z[seq(which(z$X1 == 'start') + 1, which(z$X1 == 'end') - 1),]
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> c  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron, what if I want to extract the entire row between those values including all 3 columns?

Comment: @ZT_Geo then use this output as the row index while subsetting the data frame: `z[seq(which(z$X1 == 'start') + 1, which(z$X1 == 'end') - 1),]`

Answer (score 1):

- We can use

```
library(dplyr)

z |> slice((which(X1 == "start")+1 ): (which(X1 == "end")-1))
```

- Or we can use `grepl`

```
z |> slice((which(grepl("start" , X1))+1):
           (which(grepl("end" , X1))-1))
```